# Large button to power on/off items for disabled son

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, button

My husband and I have a disabled son.  We are going to build him a sensory panel wall.  We would like to have large buttons that he can push to power on/off moving toys/lights/etc.  However, we cannot find any that do this.  We have tried this: 
[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B012E8D7XW/ref=ox_sc_sfl_title_18?ie=UTF8&psc=1&smid=A2M1GBFESN1F7H](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B012E8D7XW)
But the button is too small and hard to push (he has spastic quad CP with dystonic and choreathetosis movements.) The target has to be large and easy.
My husband also tried making a wooden round spring piece over it. It is very difficult for our son to put enough pressure to turn it on.

He needs something like this with extension cord:
[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00CYGTH9I/ref=ask_ql_qh_dp_hza](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00CYGTH9I)
However, this button is momentary. It only sends power to it while he is pushing it.  We need a big button like this that will turn the power on once pushed.  Second push would turn it off.  OR if it automatically went off after a minute or two of turning it on, that would be wonderful.

I searched the internet yesterday for hours and found nothing.  Any ideas/help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: I sympathize with your situation, but shopping questions are off-topic here. Since you clearly don't have an engineering background, my recommendation would be for you to find a "maker space" in your area, and see whether some of the members there might be interested in giving you advice and/or assistance on this project. I know that the ones in my area (New England) have interests in this area, doing things like 3-D printing custom prostheses for child amputees.

Comment: Try to find a local makerspace. There will hopefully be someone in your area who are willing and able to help you combine that big red momentary button with a microcontroller and some relays, in order to make what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use a latching relay with the switch like Crouzet PJRS110A. Use the switch to activate the relay and the relay to switch the device.

Answer (score 0):

If your handy you may want to make your own.

Buy some nice toggle buttons with metal shafts and use wood or plastic to create your own cover. The cover should have a hole in the back that press fits, or glues, onto the metal button.

[image]

If you need it really big, you may want to use multiple momentary switches per cover, and add a circuit to do the latching/unlatching function.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, I would use standard wall switches or "doorbell" buttons mounted onto a wooden/MDF panel. What I mean is things like this, but not wall-mounted:

[image]

You should be able to do this reliably with standard DIY equipment. For the wiring behind, I would recommend using redoable WAGO clamps so that things can be rewired as necessary. This would be a standard solution, the switches are large and basically impossible to break. (The good ones can be stood on without any damage!)